# How to Set City for Facebook Test User?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, userlocation

For the purpose of getting Facebook 'user_location' permission , I need to set city location for Facebook Test user which is created from Facebook Developer console. When I enter the city name "The answer provided was invalid" error is occur. How to Set City for Facebook Test User ?

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. Cities are represented as pages, but test users can not interact with any pages from the “live” realm of Facebook. To do your own testing, use a real user account instead of a test user. As for review, the people doing those have accounts available for that, that should not require a specific test user specified by the app.